# Integrate with a jar

Tags: java, jar

just a quick question. I have a jar file and I want to integrate it within my project. The decompiled version of the jar file looks like this:

```
public abstract class SinglyLinkedList

protected SinglyLinkedList.Item head;

public void addFront(String s) {
if (head == null) {
    head = new SinglyLinkedList.Item(s);
}
else {
    SinglyLinkedList.Item insert = new SinglyLinkedList.Item(s);
    next = head;
    head = insert;
}
}

public void add(String[] array) { String[] arrayOfString;
int j = (arrayOfString = array).length; for (int i = 0; i < j; i++) 
{ String s = arrayOfString[i];
addFront(s);
}
}

public String toString()
{
if (head == null) {
    return "empty list";
}
String s = "";

for (SinglyLinkedList.Item helper = head; next != null; helper = next) {
    s = String.valueOf(s) + value + ", ";
    s = String.valueOf(s) + value;
    return s;
}

public abstract void sort();

protected class Item
{
    public Item next;
    public String value;
    public Item(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
}
```

Now I want to create a new linked list in my other class, but this doesnt work:

```
private SinglyLinkedList linkedlist;

public SelectionSortableList(){
    this.linkedlist = new SinglyLinkedList();
}
```

He cannot instantiate it. Can please somebody tell me why he don't want to instantiate it? Thank you in beforehand.

Answer (score 2):

```
public abstract class SinglyLinkedList
```

Because this is an `abstract` class. `abstract` classes cannot be instantiated.

You need to `extend` it and implement the following `abstract` method:

```
public abstract void sort();
```

---

Once you extend the class all the non-private method will be directly accessible into your super class.

Your class should be like this:

```
class SelectionSortableList extends SinglyLinkedList {
  @Override
  public void sort() {
    // provide you implementation here.
  }
}
```

Comment: I've tried to extend it before, but I only get "SinglyLinkedList cannot be resolved to a type". I know, that I cannot instantiate abstract classes, but how can I integrate it in my other class, so that I can work with it? Is there  a different method, to create a linked list?

Comment: I've tried this before, but if I only write "public class SelectionSortableList extends SinglyLinkedList" I get "SinglyLinkedList cannot be resolved to a type"

Comment: The above code looks like to be hand written code, It have a lot of compilation issue. Please fix them.

Comment: This is a decompiled version of the jar. I don't have access to it and cannot fix it. But it should work. They gave it to me for homework and I should work with it. The homework isn't that complicated, if I just could create a new list, then I could actually being able to write the sorting method.

Comment: Ok. I would suggest you implement the `SinglyLinkedList` abstract method in `SelectionSortableList`. Then use the `SelectionSortableList` for creating the instance of the `SinglyLinkedList` and use them as list.

Comment: I already wrote that class and I can only create new Items, but not a new linked list. But actually I have to work with that jar file. But if I try it with the jar file, he even doesn't want to create new Items. I have removed that jar file several times and insert it again and replaced it in the folders, but nothing really canges. I have absolutely no clue, how I should do that. i know you cannot help me that much, because you are not in front of my computer, but still thank you, that you take the time for me and trying to help me with my problems. I'll ask later in my university :)